# How to add text in editText from JsonArray received in StringResponse

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am trying to set text of editText From jsonArray which I received as a string in StringRequest. Data is being received in string successfully but i'm unable to set text of editText from that String.

```
private void getStructure() throws JSONException {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(modifyStructureActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                JSONObject struct_info = new JSONObject(response);
                admin_name2.setText(struct_info.getString("adminName"));
                org_name2.setText(struct_info.getString("name"));
                org_cat2.setText(struct_info.getString("category"));
                org_sub_cat2.setText(struct_info.getString("subCategory"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(modifyStructureActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError
        {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("modifyStructure","modifyStructure");
            return map;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(modifyStructureActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: did you get any log error? post here

Comment: 08-12 14:21:27.974 27384-27384/reviewcollector.fyp.com.structuredrc W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"id":"1","name":"bsjwt","category":"gsusuw","subCategory":"gsuwi","adminName":"vdjsf"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
08-12 14:21:27.974 27384-27384/reviewcollector.fyp.com.structuredrc W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
08-12 14:21:27.974 27384-27384/reviewcollector.fyp.com.structuredrc W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)

Comment: you are parsing json array to object which causes error

Comment: please tell me a better way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are Parsing JsonArray to JsonObject, you are getting JsonArray from server and you are trying for parse with JsonObject which cause the `JSONException`

**Try this,**

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
JSONObject struct_info = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
admin_name2.setText(struct_info.getString("adminName"));
org_name2.setText(struct_info.getString("name"));
org_cat2.setText(struct_info.getString("category"));
org_sub_cat2.setText(struct_info.getString("subCategory"));
```